# Produce css value based on boolean value from scss file

Tags: css, reactjs

I have the following which works fine where I am using in line style to decide the percentage 
values based on a boolean value.

Is there a way I could prevent using inline styling and instead pass this styling to my scss file  and still be able to perform this logic more elegantly?

Working copy with inline styling.

```
const MyPage = ({isSmall}) => {
  return (
    <div>
        <div style={{flex: `0 0 ${isSmall ? '50%' : '33%'}`}}>
          hello
        </div>
    </div>
  );
};

export default MyPage;
```

Looking to be able to move my css to my scss file and use that as a className instead but still 
be able to toggle the percentage value based on the boolean isSmall prop value.

Move it to scss file.

```
.flexer {
  flex: '0 0 33%' // some way to make the 33% be dynamic and not hard code like this to be able to switch its value between 50% and 33%
}
```

Then use this flexer class instead of inline css.

Is this possible? Or any better elegant way to achieve this instead of inline?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can set boolean state and change class name depends on this state inside the className then you can modifiy it in css

```
const MyPage = ({isSmall}) => {

  const [isSmall,setIsSmall] = useState(false);
  return (
    <div>
        <div className={isBigClass `${isSmall} ?  "isSmallClass" : ""}`} >
          hello
        </div>
    </div>
  );
};

export default MyPage;
```

Comment: Thanks this sparked the idea. But think I can make do without the state handling just use the prop to switch between 2 css classes.

Comment: Sure you can make it, I just wrote with the state as an example, you are welcome.